# Bazel: local access to file nearby

Tags: c++, bazel

I want to read a file nearby from cc file. I've inserted the `data` attribute, but it seems it doesn't find the data.txt nearby.

Structure:

```
├── root
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── data.txt
│   └── main.cc
└── WORKSPACE
```

In the BUILD file:

```
cc_binary(
name = "test",
srcs = ["main.cc"],
data = ["data.txt"]
)
```

In the main.cc file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

ifstream myReadFile;
 myReadFile.open("data.txt");

 if (!myReadFile.good()){
  cout << "FILE not good!" << endl;
  return 1;
 }

cout << "FILE is good!" << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building from the top-level directory (the directory that contains `WORKSPACE`, using `bazel build root:test`, and you run your code with `bazel-bin/root/test`, the file should be specified as `root/data.txt`.

Comment: You're right. But, there should be a way to access files in a package-relative manner. Sub-projects aren't necessarily aware of the whole project structure.

Comment: I know; but bazel is not a package-management tool, it's a build tool. Presumably, after you've built everything, you move these files to their final destinations, and that's where your code should access them from. The normal use case for the `data` parameter is for tests, where you want to specify some test file, and you can get the top-level directory from the TEST_DATA_DIR environment variable when you run tests with `bazel test`. or some such (look at the docs).